# A Div should have the same width as previous (or inside) Div - Without Javascript?

Tags: html, css

My example is only working with a line of Javascript from jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/TFLMX/4/

When I change the html of class center into

```
div class="center">Here is</div>
```

the pink div gets the width of center, but is this possible without javascript?
Maybe the smaller div must be in center div? Thanks!

Here it goes wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/TFLMX/10/

The div 'smaller' must have at any time the same dynamic width as 'center'.
But the text in 'smaller' must get a word-wrap if it becomes to small to display the text on one line.

Comment: Not possible without javascript/jquery..

Comment: With jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/76rSP/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i used this logic and works as u want:

> `max-width+padding+margin` of second div < `min-width+padding+margin` of previous div

```
.smaller {
    background: pink;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    max-width:100px;
    margin:0 5px;
}
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/TFLMX/41)

Comment: But if you write after "Here is" again some more text [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/TFLMX/32/) , than the pink is forever smaller. It must have at any time the same width as the orange div.

Comment: you said that pink div shoud be smaller ever. " The 'smaller' should not be wider than 'center' "

Comment: Sorry, I mean they should have the same width. With ever smaller I mean it must get its text into smaller "stapled" position. -word-wrap

Comment: The Pink looks good, but the Orange div must get more text, not the pink one. [A lot more clear example](http://jsfiddle.net/TFLMX/57/)

Comment: On your current Demo: As soon as someone puts more text in the '.center' (main element) div, the width of '.smaller' must catch the width of 'center'. And more text can fit on one line in '.smaller'.

Comment: @projektalex First make a clear fiddle with all possibilities and ask a new question with all issue.

Comment: I'm going with your answer and only set the max-width to normal width and centered it with margin 0 auto. Sorry about unclear question....